# Turn old phone camera into raspberry pi camera

Tags: raspicam, picamera

I don't really have the chance to get a raspberry pi camera. But I have tons of old phones and tons of phone cameras. Is there any way I can turn them into a camera that works with raspberry pi ?

Comment: yes ... there is a way to do almost anything

Comment: It is possible. All you have to do is get a specification for the camera, design and build an interface and write the software. You would be better to stop buying phones then you could afford to buy a supported camera.

Comment: The phoned are not mine tbh. They are mostly my friends' , relatives' old phones

Comment: see https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=8270

Answer (score 1):

I use a linux solution called 'motion' to stream from both Raspberry PI Cameras and from remote IP based cameras.   If you don't want to have to build motion on your PI there is a image based distro called 'MotionEyes' which uses motion and has a nice web based interface so its simple to install and configure.

https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki/Installation

For your phones there is a iOS/Android app called 'Periscope' which turn out phone into a RTSP web camera.   So you can stream video/audio from it.

Works very well and certainly for iOS its free..
https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/periscope-hd-h-264-rtsp-cam/id1095600218

Comment: Hey thanks but unfortunately the phones are not working. The cameras are working. I ve taken them apart from the phone